# Is there a maximum limit on the distance beyond which we can't resolve an image using a reflector telescope in the visible light spectrum

Tags: optics, diffraction, telescopes

Through Rayleigh's Criterion, it is implied that there is a maximum distance beyond which we cannot resolute an object. This limitation is due to the limitation in the size of the aperture of the lense. Rayleigh's Criterion is founded upon diffraction which is exhibited by light after interacting with lenses/ refractor telescopes. But reflector telescopes, which use spherical mirrors, should not diffract light, right? 
So is there a maximum limitation not a maximum or am I not understanding this correctly?

Comment: oh is the diffraction due to just the opening of the telescope and not related to the lens/ mirror?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct answer.

Comment: @my2cts I get it now,thanks